# GCP Transcoder API mov/mp4 to hls/fmp4 no audio output (on IOS)

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, video-streaming, fmp4

I use the GCP Transcoder API with the following configuration:

- NodeJS 12
- Firebase Storage
- Firestore DB
- GCP CDN
- job start on upload (firebase function)

  ```
    const config = {
      "elementaryStreams": [
        {
          "videoStream": {
            "codec": "h264",
            "tune": 'zerolatency',
            "preset": 'superfast',
            "heightPixels": 360,
            "widthPixels": 640,
            "bitrateBps": 400000,
            "rateControlMode": "vbr",
            "frameRate": 30,
            "crfLevel": 26,
            "gopMode": { "gopDuration": "1.0s",  }
          },
          "key": "video-stream0"
        },
        {
          "videoStream": {
            "codec": "h264",
            "tune": 'zerolatency',
            "preset": 'superfast',
            "heightPixels": 480,
            "widthPixels": 854,
            "bitrateBps": 1500000,
            "rateControlMode": "vbr",
            "frameRate": 60,
            "crfLevel": 26,
            "gopMode": { "gopDuration": "1.0s",  }
          },
          "key": "video-stream1"
        },
        {
          "videoStream": {
            "codec": "h264",
            "tune": 'zerolatency',
            "preset": 'superfast',
            "heightPixels": 720,
            "widthPixels": 1280,
            "bitrateBps": 3000000,
            "rateControlMode": "vbr",
            "frameRate": 60,
            "crfLevel": 26,
            "gopMode": { "gopDuration": "1.0s",  }
          },
          "key": "video-stream2"
        },
        {
          "key": "audio-stream0",
          "audioStream":  {
            "codec":  "aac",
            "bitrateBps":  128000,
            "channelCount": 2,
            "channelLayout": ["fl", "fr"],
            "sampleRateHertz": 48000,
          }
        }
      ],
      "muxStreams": [
        {
          "key": "video-only-sd",
          "container": "fmp4",
          "elementaryStreams": [ "video-stream0" ],
          "segmentSettings": { 
            "segmentDuration": { "seconds": "2.0s" },
            "individualSegments": true 
          },
        },
        {
          "key": "video-only-md",
          "container": "fmp4",
          "elementaryStreams": [ "video-stream1" ],
          "segmentSettings": { 
            "segmentDuration": { "seconds": "2.0s" },
            "individualSegments": true 
          },
        },
        {
          "key": "video-only-hd",
          "container": "fmp4",
          "elementaryStreams": [ "video-stream2" ],
          "segmentSettings": { 
            "segmentDuration": { "seconds": "2.0s" },
            "individualSegments": true 
          },
        },
        {
          "key": "audio-only",
          "container": "fmp4",
          "elementaryStreams": [ "audio-stream0" ],
          "segmentSettings": { 
            "segmentDuration": { "seconds": "2.0s" },
            "individualSegments": true 
          }
        }
      ],
      "manifests": [
        {
          "fileName": "master.m3u8",
          "type": "HLS",
          "muxStreams": [
            "video-only-sd",
            "video-only-md",
            "video-only-hd",
            "audio-only"
          ]
        }
      ],
  ```

Excerpt of the output:[image]

The videos run wonderfully on various players, also adapt to the bandwidth, but the sound is missing on iPhones.
Possible reason: The audio files were generated, but the number differs from the generated video files. At about 10 sec. video, there is one more audio file.

Any idea what I have forgotten or overlooked or wrongly defined or interpreted?

Comment: In the meantime I got it going:
Changed the container to 'ts' (instead of fmp4), the job creates no audio-mux, and changed the config of the elementaryStreams to "elementaryStreams": [ "video-stream0", "audio-stream0" ] as mentioned by @Klabauterman

Answer (score 0):

In ElementaryStreams you define your audio and video streams. MuxStreams contain mixed streams of video and audio which is your desired output. You need to add your audio stream here.

Instead of

```
"elementaryStreams": [ "video-stream0" ],
```

Write

```
"elementaryStreams": [ "video-stream0", "audio-stream0" ],
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but unfortunately this doesn't help. On the contrary - this breaks the job.